# Why do my components share the ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am learning Kotlin and writing a small app. Currently, I am struggling with dependency injection and scope.

We are using currently using one Activity that has multiple screens. The navigation is done using compose. On the last screen, there are 5 identical components.

```
@Composable
fun GameScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(32.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        DiceView()
        DiceView()
        DiceView()
        DiceView()
        DiceView()
    }
}
```

The DiceView is a composable and looks as follows:

```
@Composable
fun DiceView(
    viewModel: DiceViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
//    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<DiceViewModel>()
    val state = viewModel.state.value
    Log.i("XX", System.identityHashCode(viewModel).toString())
    Log.i("XX", LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current.toString())
    Dice(viewModel = viewModel, state = state)
}

@Composable
fun Dice(viewModel: DiceViewModel, state: DiceState) {
    Button(onClick = {
        viewModel.onEvent(
            DiceEvent.RollDice
        )
    }) {
        Text(text = state.eyes.toString())
    }
}
```

Full code available at: https://github.com/smaillimp/Yatzy/tree/ca59a6c

If I press the button, the number of eyes on all dice change. The reason behind it is that all composables use the same ViewModel instance. I assume this is because of the same NavBackStackEntry entry (confirmed by the logging). However, I am not sure what I should do to avoid this. I only found answers asking the opposite (i.e. how to share view models over multiple composables, but not how to avoid that).

Any pointers towards an answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The navigation is done using compose

Jetpack Compose is a library that's used for rendering UI by using composables. It doesn't have much to do with navigating from one screen to another one, if that's what you meant.

I see that in the `GameScreen` composable the `DiceView` composables are called without any arguments, like this:

```
DiceView()
```

As a result, every `DiceView` composable is assigned in its `viewModel` parameter the value returned from `hiltViewModel()`. That's because it has been defined this way:

```
@Composable
fun DiceView(
    viewModel: DiceViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
       ...
}
```

Probably, the method call `hiltViewModel()` always returns the same instance of a `DiceViewModel` object. Also, probably the Hilt library is used for dependency injection in your code.

So, due to this, all five `DiceView` composables that are created are injected with the same `DiceViewModel` instance. As a result, when a method in the viewModel is called, like this one

```
viewModel.onEvent(DiceEvent.RollDice)
```

then it affects all composables that have been injected with and share this same viewModel instance.

> I am not sure what I should do to avoid this

Therefore, to avoid this behavior, you can just not inject all `DiceView` composables with the same viewModel instance.
For example, you can do something like this:

```
@Composable
fun DiceView(
    viewModel: DiceViewModel = DiceViewModel()
) {
       ...
}
```

This way every time a `DiceView` composable is created, it uses a new instance of the `DiceViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This does not work since a dependency is injected into `DiceViewModel()` using hilt.
I am not yet sure how to avoid the issue, but I have started from another point now. That enabled me to work around it for now.

Comment: @wrYch another way would be to change the way the `DiceViewModel` is defined to be instantiated when using hilt, so that every time `hiltViewModel()` is called it will create a new instance instead of reusing the same one.